# how to render ajax return in cakephp 3.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a table that have checkboxes inside. after select it how to return a sum of values from table in modal before confirm the form? and how to render the ajax response from controller?
in my view

```
    $("#envia-vendas").ajaxForm({
  url: '../vendas/confirmar', 
  type: 'post', 
  success: function (data) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    console.log(data);
  },
```

in my controller

```
//dostuf
            if($this->request->is('ajax')){
              $sum = $sum;
              $this->render('ajax/confirmado', 'ajax');
              echo 'bal';
              $this->set('text', 'test');
              $this->set('_serialize', ['text']);

            }
```

how to print the result in the view without reloading page?

Comment: So you're wondering how you would inject your returned data into a modal? Are you already getting the data back inside of your javascript or is your php not working either?

Comment: it's is only returning the echo 'bal' of the controller;

Comment: What are you wanting to return from your php?

Comment: an array that contains the values selected and asking for user to confirm this values.

Comment: Alright, assuming i'm following you correctly, what you can do is instead of hitting a server script to generate an array for you, you could use javascript for all of this. When you "submit" the form have jquery intercept the event, grab the forms data, and then insert and format it inside of the modal with a confirmation button that would then truly submit the form. One sec and ill implement a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this fiddle does is grabs all of your inputs, then pops up a modal after the values and names have been injected for confirmation.

It should give you a good starting point. What this is setup to do is give you the confirmation screen without the need for additional server calls.

Just set your action to the route that you want to pass the information to for server interactions.

HTML

```
<form id="test-form" method="post" action="your/action/here">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit-form" value="submit" />
</form>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="form-info-wrapper">

  </div>
  <a class="confirm">Confirm Information</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $('body').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).parent('form').serializeArray();

    $('.form-info-wrapper').empty();

    for(_data in data)
    {
        $('.form-info-wrapper').append(data[_data].name + ': ' + data[_data].value);
    }

    $('.modal').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.confirm').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

    $('#test-form').submit();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojaeacps/2/